# How To Execute Native Commands In Java?

Tags: java, shell, command, native

I know very well how to execute commands via Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) and handle the output, but this is VERY limited.

Take Windows for example (Vista specifically but that shouldn't matter).

How can I execute commands like 'echo', 'cd', 'md', 'rd', and any other command rooted inside of the cmd.exe through ProcessBuilder (or whatever class) in Java?

Comment: ProcessBuilder is the correct class (http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Is there something specific you are having trouble accomplishing?

Comment: It's worth noting that each of the commands you have listed are able to be done through the Java libraries. I know you might not have every function you need, but I would recommend using the Java libraries whenever you can, resorting to ProcessBuilder to do it only when necessary.

Comment: @glowcoder Of course.  They were only examples of commands rooted inside of the actual command prompt and not the system itself.  I won't be using any of those particular commands to carry out actual programmatic tasks.  That would be silly.  Java has the ability to do so.  If you must know, I just need Java to be able to execute all/most native commands from a Command Shell Wrapper I am making.

Comment: @KyleMahan Yes.  Making a Command Shell Wrapper.  Basically a command prompt run by Java with a GUI.  Mainly for use on some particular UNIX machines on which I can't access the terminal.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, you can make a custom wrapper or use Apache Commons exec: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/tutorial.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just call `cmd /c dir` rather than just `dir` in Runtime.exec or ProcessBuilder or some other way to run external applications in JAVA.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you happen to know the equivalent on UNIX?

Comment: Just for the use of anyone who happens to see this answer, the equivalent in on *nix systems would be:
 `sh -c <command>`

Although, I would recommend Apache Commons Exec or something similar to take care of all of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to leverage the Ant libraries and put together a programmed version of `<exec ...>` ([Ant Exec Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html)). This also gives you access to all kinds of Ant-supported input/output processing and filtering.

This is not writing an Ant XML script here, but *calling Ant from your code*.